Need help in getting the correct JOLT Spec for the given input & expected output JSONs
I'm trying to transform a piece of nested JSON into flatten JSON Using JOLT Transform
Input JSON :
[
  {
    "product_id": 44685238,
    "part_id": 43375079,
    "part_name": "506250-R4",
    "partner_parts": [
      {
        "id": 542063727,
        "name": "506250-R4",
        "partner_id": 34302479,
        "partner_name": "SIBELCO",
        "alternate_part_names": null
      },
      {
        "id": 542063728,
        "name": "506250-R4",
        "partner_id": 34303125,
        "partner_name": "LG HAUSYS",
        "alternate_part_names": null
      },
      {
        "id": 542063729,
        "name": "506250-R4",
        "partner_id": 34303949,
        "partner_name": "SHAW INDUSTRIES",
        "alternate_part_names": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "product_id": 44685238,
    "part_id": 43375387,
    "part_name": "Foundations",
    "partner_parts": null
  },
  {
    "product_id": 44685238,
    "part_id": 43376665,
    "part_name": "W01‑02198",
    "partner_parts": [
      {
        "id": 542065051,
        "name": "W01‑02198",
        "partner_id": 34302479,
        "partner_name": "SIBELCO",
        "alternate_part_names": null
      },
      {
        "id": 542065052,
        "name": "W01‑02198",
        "partner_id": 34303125,
        "partner_name": "LG HAUSYS",
        "alternate_part_names": null
      }
    ]
  }
]

Expected Output JSON :
[
{
  {
  "product_id": 44685238,
  "part_id": 43375079,
  "part_name": "506250-R4",
  "partner_parts.id": 542063727,
  "partner_parts.name": "506250-R4",
  "partner_parts.partner_id": 34302479,
  "partner_parts.partner_name": "SIBELCO",
  "partner_parts.alternate_part_names": {},
  "partner_parts.id": 542063728,
  "partner_parts.name": "506250-R4",
  "partner_parts.partner_id": 34303125,
  "partner_parts.partner_name": "LG HAUSYS",
  "partner_parts.alternate_part_names": {},
  "partner_parts.id": 542063729,
  "partner_parts.name": "506250-R4",
  "partner_parts.partner_id": 34303949,
  "partner_parts.partner_name": "SHAW INDUSTRIES",
  "partner_parts.alternate_part_names": {},
  },
  {
  "product_id": 44685238,
  "part_id": 43375387,
  "part_name": "Foundations",
  "part_description": {},
  "sole_sourced": false,
  "single_sourced": false,
  "revenue_at_risk": 302000000,
  "max_recovery_time": {},
  "max_recovery_time_unit": {},
  "average_recovery_time": {},
  "average_recovery_time_unit": {},
  "spend": {},
  "part_category": {},
  "partner_parts": {},
  },
  {
  "product_id": 44685238,
  "part_id": 43376665,
  "part_name": "W01‑02198",
  "partner_parts.id": 542065051,
  "partner_parts.name": "W01‑02198",
  "partner_parts.partner_id": 34302479,
  "partner_parts.partner_name": "SIBELCO",
  "partner_parts.alternate_part_names": {},
  "partner_parts.id": 542065052,
  "partner_parts.name": "W01‑02198",
  "partner_parts.partner_id": 34303125,
  "partner_parts.partner_name": "LG HAUSYS",
  "partner_parts.alternate_part_names": {},
  "partner_parts.id": 542065053,
  "partner_parts.name": "W01‑02198",
  "partner_parts.partner_id": 34303949,
  "partner_parts.partner_name": "SHAW INDUSTRIES",
  "partner_parts.alternate_part_names": {}
  }
}
]

I need a JOLT Spec for the above use case, I've tried multiple specs but unable to get the exact results.
Thank you for checking it out.
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................

First of all, the expected JSON is invalid, since there cannot be the identical key names
in any of the object. Moreover, the logic is not clear enough, as an example :
there are some attributes such as part_description, sole_sourced, single_sourced..etc the source of them is uncertain.

Please share what experience you have already done, and what were the results
